# Pronunciation of the second syllable in “ancient” and “conscience”

Tags: pronunciation

I have looked up the pronunciation of these two words, ***ancient*** and ***conscience***, in the Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary as well as other online dictionaries such as dictionary.com and dictionary.cambridge.org. Their pronunciations are given as `/ˈeɪnʃənt/` and `/ˈkɒnʃəns/`. However, I have heard a lot of American people pronounce them as `/ˈeɪntʃənt/` and `/ˈkɒntʃəns/`, meaning they pronounce the starting sound of the second syllable as `/tʃ/` instead of `/ʃ/`. Is this considered a mispronunciation by some people or is it actually a correct pronunciation in American English?

Comment: I'm American and I have never heard the latter pronunciations. I don't even know if you could tell the difference even if the /t/ sound were stressed, because it would be immediately subsumed by the /ʃ/ sound.

Comment: Tom D., I have marked this post as a “duplicate” because I think Araucaria’s answer to the linked question also answers yours—please let me know if you disagree. Another related question is [since you = sinchu correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348143/since-you-sinchu-correc)